# wifi suddenly wont connect?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I gt my new laptop with ubuntu 12.04..
My wireless connection was working fine till yesterday.
now suddenly it doesnt detect at all. it doesnt detect any new connections either .my wired(eternet) connection works.
i have tried rfkill.. they are all unblocked.

iwconfig returns:

```
siddarthcr@SID:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig returns:

```
siddarthcr@SID:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:86:7a:3f:74:84  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7686:7aff:fe3f:7484/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:814 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:391259 (391.2 KB)  TX bytes:127493 (127.4 KB)
          Interrupt:42 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:19962 (19.9 KB)  TX bytes:19962 (19.9 KB)
```

wlan0 is not detecing at all:

```
siddarthcr@SID:~$ ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

siddarthcr@SID:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(wireless|network)"
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:020c
```

Pls help..any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: nm-tools doesnt show any wireless connection either :(

Answer (score 0):

Just  try running  aptitude   update   then  upgrade
 from the terminal    Sudo aptitude

This  fixes  a bunch of stuff

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. i updated and upgraded through aptitude but still no solution..

Comment: i luv whn 2 bad spelng usrs cht wit ech othr.